# OnItemClickListener and OnClickListener in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom view for each row in a custom ListAdapter and I am trying to perform onClick action and get the row position in the list where the click came from.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:id="@+id/itemRoot" android:clickable="false">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/itemTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemTxt" android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/itemTxt"
        android:id="@+id/amountTxt" android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_width="match_parent"></TextView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/delBtn" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/delete" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"></ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to figure out when TextView or ImageView is clicked, I also need to know what row in the list it came form. I have tried using OnItemClickListener and it works fine to get the row where the click comes from. However, once I register an OnClick listener for the views, the onItemClicked() method gets skipped and onClick() is executed straight away, but there is no way of getting the row position that the view is in(or at least not that I know if).

If I set clickable to false for the views, then onItemClicked get called and I tried manually calling performClick() on the given view. But this only works for the root element (RelativeLayout), and if click comes from TextView inside the layout the click doesn't propagate.

I can't really figure out how to get both position in the list and perform onClick action.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Alex

Comment: In your layout when positioning a view relative to another view, you should specify the anchor's id without the **`+`** sign: `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/itemTxt"` and `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/itemTxt"`. The `"@+id/itemTxt"` is used when creating a new id for a view (so in the `android:id` attribute's value).

Comment: All of that code is auto-generated, but I will keep that in mind :) Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could assign the proper `OnClickListener` to each `ImageView` and `TextView` from inside your `ListAdapter`'s overridden `getView` method.

Inside that method you know the item's position, so you can pass it to the custom listener classes, and use it there as you want:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO: instantiate the layout 
    // here I call a super method
    final View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    final TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemTxt);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.i("Click", "TextView clicked on row " + position);
        }
    });
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.delBtn);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.i("Click", "ImageView clicked on row " + position);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks rekaszeru, that's actually really neat and nice solution.

Answer (score 5):

The other possible option to have the OnClickListener in the same class as the creating activity is to add to the activity `implements OnItemClickListener`.

```
public class DisplayListCustom extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
```

Then set the custom list to listen

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
list.setClickable(true);
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
list.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listItems));
```

Finally in the onItemClick return, you can find the inner views by using resource ID

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    LinearLayout listItem = (LinearLayout) v;
    TextView clickedItemView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.name);
    String clickedItemString = clickedItemView.getText().toString();
    Log.i("DisplayListCustom", "Click detected " + clickedItemString + ", position " + Integer.toString(position));
```

This is the solution I went with.  I used LinearLayout for my custom layout container, but I assume the same applies to RelativeLayout.

Comment: nice! I prefer this approach over the anonymous classes approach that rekaszeru suggested

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your TextView etc, override the click method, do the appropriate actions and then the trick is to return false so it's then propagated to the listview.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a method to override that will return false and trick into thinking that event wasn't consumed. Thanks