# Click on ListItem in ListView does not respond

Tags: android, android-listview

Click on ListItem in ListView does not respond however longClickListener is responding. And I want to start a new activity when the user clicks on the list view item.

What I tried:

```
android:clickable="false" // and true - not working
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" // no change with or without it
```

Why is the onItemClickListener not responding ?

MainActivity.xml

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private ListView remindersList;
    private ImageView createEvent; 
    private ImageView deleteEvent;
    private TextView noRemindersSet;
    private String[] values = {"One", "Two", "Three"};  
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createEvent = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    deleteEvent = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    createEvent.setOnClickListener(this);
    deleteEvent.setOnClickListener(this);
    remindersList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    ListViewArrayAdapter adapter = new ListViewArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, 
             android.R.id.list, values);
    //setting the adapter
    remindersList.setAdapter(adapter);
    remindersList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    remindersList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Log.d("s click","id: ");
        }});

    remindersList.setLongClickable(true);
    remindersList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id)
        {
            Log.d("long clicked","id: " + id);
            return true;
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Array Adapter

```
public class ListViewArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

private final Context context;
String[] values;
private TextView textView;

public ListViewArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] values) {
    super(context, resource, values);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
  return rowView;
    }

}
```

List_View.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#01B0F1"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:text="@string/textview"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set TextView `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` 
`android:focusable="false"`

Comment: Have you put setClickable in code, ex list.setClickable(true); maybe something changes when moving from xml to actual display. Since that is only difference from longClick.

Comment: @SilentKiller is right. If this doesn't work you can define an onClickListner on your arrayAdapter.

Comment: @SilentKiller nope it did not work out.

Comment: @Dyna Adding the following code to getView() method works..
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) 
            {
              Log.d("click","click");
             }
         });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this method on your adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("s click","id: ");
                Intent i = new Intent(context, yourActivity.class);  //change your activity to the one you want to launch
                context.startActivity(i); //you already had your context defined above so just use it to start the activity

            }
        });

    textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    return rowView;
    }

}
```

And remove your `remindersList.setOnItemClickListener`. This will work ;)

Answer (score 2):

set TextView

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

this will make your list focusable
 else focus move to TextView and your listview is not getting clicked.

[- ListView Sample with TextView](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.nl/2011/08/focus-problems-with-list-rows-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

try to remove implements statement in your MainActivtiy.

Comment: does this can solve above problem..?? what is relation between `implements onCLickListener` and `onItemClickListener()`.. ???

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090666/onitemclicklistener-and-onclicklistener-in-listview this describes the problem with both listeners

Comment: in that question requirement was different here different. in that question he wants to click on imgeview as well as textview. please unserstand requirement clearly first then answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
remindersList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos,
                long id) {

            Log.d("s click","pos: "+ pos);
             Log.d("s click","id: "+ id);
        }});
```