# ListView with EditText and OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, click, focusable

I have a ListView with a custom Adapter which populates Items with an EditText and a TextView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_choice_prob"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_choice_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/et_choice_prob"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/et_choice_prob"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

If I want to set an `OnItemClickListener` it gets never called, due to the EditText stealing the focus.

Another thread mentioned that I should set `focusable` to `false`, which will remove the ability to actually edit the TextView.

I have also tried to set `descendantFocusability` of the `ListView` to any available option withot success.

The Adapter is doing nothing fancy, but I'll provide source on request. Everything else is done in the same way on another `ListFragment` and works.

Comment: did you tried to add onclicklistener on each childs of your view ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6090713/2667946

Comment: Yeah... am already figuring out that kind of custom solution. But it really bugs me why that stupid `OnItemClickListener` did not trigger

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code in yout `EditText` tag

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Set `setOnClickListener` for `RelativeLayout` while inflating list item views in `getView` method of your adapter. Your `EditText` does not match with parent so this must be work when you click other side of list row.

Comment: actually same solution as in the first comment on the question from @JulienGenoud

Comment: After searching  in SO, I think this should be the proper way to solve this problem, though it has too much boilerplate code here. But any other solution like `descendantFocusability` didn't work for me. Besides, I can't understand why `focusable` may interrupt `onItemClickListener` in listview.

Answer (score 0):

Set onTouchlistener on view of individual item in adapter class. Also you have to manage the state of list such that when list is being scrolled, onTouch should be disabled and when not scrolled, onTouch should work as usual. It works fine on recycler view in my project. Should work with ListView as well.